# Rendering a charts after dynamically creating holders for them doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing something wrong with the timings here, but cannot figure out what.

If I create the charts with 1000ms timeout they render properly.
Otherwise if I try to fetch the data in the constructor or in an early lifecycle hook, and then render in another hook somewhere after HighCharts won't find the  with the id projected into the template, thus it will not render. Dev tools show the div as present, but it is not at the time of a function call.

I want to solve this properly before building and update functionality. Thanks for your help!

XyComponent.ts:

```
 export class XYComponent implements OnInit {
     public chartsHolder: ChartObject[];
     public Response: ResponseDto[];
     public xyInfo: XyInfoObject[];

     constructor(
         private dataService: xyzService
     ) {    

     }

     ngOnInit() {
         this.getChartData();
         setTimeout(() => {
             this.chartsHolder = new Array<Highcharts.ChartObject>();
             this.xyInfo.forEach((element) => {

                 this.chartsHolder.push(Highcharts.chart(element.chartHolderId, <any>this.createChartOptions(element.chartName, 250, 250, element.displayValue / 1000000)));
             });
         }, 1000);
     }

     //ngAfterViewInit() {
     //    this.chartsHolder = new Array<Highcharts.ChartObject>();
     //    this.xyInfo.forEach((element) => {
     //        
     //        this.chartsHolder.push(Highcharts.chart(element.chartHolderId, <any>this.createChartOptions(element.chartName, 250, 250, element.displayValue / 1000000)));
     //    });
     //}

     private getChartData() {
         this.xyInfo = new Array<xyInfoObject>();
         this.dataService.getXyInfo().then((value) => {
             for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                 this.xyInfo.push(this.CreateDesiredObjectFromResponseDto(value[i], i));
             }
         });
         // Nor does it work if I apply the code here in a .then function
         //.then(() => {
         // this.chartsHolder = new Array<Highcharts.ChartObject>();
         // this.xyInfo.forEach((element) => {
         //         this.chartsHolder.push(Highcharts.chart(element.chartHolderId, <any>this.createChartOptions(element.chartName, 250, 250, element.displayValue / 1000000)));
         //     }); 
         //});      
     }
```

The template for XyComponent:

```
 <div class="gauge-grid-container mdl-shadow--8dp">
     <div id="rtd-grid-title" class="">
         <h4 class="">Xy title</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="gauge-grid" *ngFor="let instance of xyInfo">
         <div class="cell">
             <div class="">
                <!-- Here I set the ID, might this do something with the issue? -->
                 <div id="{{instance.chartHolderId}}"></div>
                 <div class="last-update-date">{{instance.displayDate}}</div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: why don't set your "chartsHolder" in the same loop where you set your "xyInfo" array ?

Comment: Because a div element has to exist when i call the Highcharts.chart(elementId, ...) function and the template is based on an ngFor on the xyInfo array. I wanted to create the charts after the divs exist for all the elements in the xyInfo array, so i can select them based on their IDs.

Comment: Since then i realized that I don't need to store all the charts since the are already stored via Highcharts.charts, i will optimize there, but the issue still exists.

Comment: xyInfo is binded to your template, I'm pretty sure when you feed it with data, your *ngFor will populate template so div will exists. I don't understand why this dosen't work if you put in your .then method ... First because you deal with async you have to find an async solution so your "chartsHolder"  set will be triggered in a then to be sure you load datas, imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly i couldn't find a solution, but only a workaround. I wait for the http response, project the html for the charts based on the count of response DTO-s then wait one second which is usually enough for the client side application to project the html (tested on many machines). And then populate the charts with data.

```
this.dataService.getXYInfo().then((value) => {
        if (value.length > 0) {
            this.dataUnavailable= false;
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                this.xyInfo.push(this.CreateChartObjectFromDTO(value[i], i));
            }
        }
        else {
            this.dataUnavailable = true;
        }
    }).then(() => {
        /* Wait 1 second before populating */
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.xyInfo.forEach((element) => {
                this.charts.push(Highcharts.chart(element.chartHolderId, <any>this.createChartOptions(element.chartName, this.calculateDimensionsForChart(), this.calculateDimensionsForChart(), element.displayValue)));
                element.isChartRendered = true;
            });

            this.StoreTimer(setInterval(() => {
                this.updateChartData();
            }, 300000));

            this.blockUpdates = false;
        }, 1000);
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.errored = true;
        this.ResetComponent();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }, 10000);
    });
```